# Evaluating DNNClassifier for multi-label classification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, multilabel-classification

I am using tensorflow DNNClassifier for multi label classification, which uses accuracy as it uses its metric. I am evaluating the model using sklearn f1 metric, which is showing quite low score. Also score from sklearn accuracy is low. Is my implementation wrong somewhere?

DNN classifier

```
embedding_feats = hub.text_embedding_column(key='text',
                         module_spec='https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2',
                         trainable=False)

dnn = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
          hidden_units=[512, 128],
          feature_columns=[embedding_feats],
          n_classes=11,
          activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
          dropout=0.1,
          optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.005))
```

DNN classifier Train Output. Val acc is 0.40

```
Training for step = 8000
Train Time (s): 52.573952436447144
Eval Metrics (Train): {'accuracy': 0.44695774, 'average_loss': 1.516403, 'loss': 193.58235, 'global_step': 8200}
Eval Metrics (Validation): {'accuracy': 0.40303582, 'average_loss': 1.6520736, 'loss': 209.30502, 'global_step': 8200}
```

Sklearn F1 score

```
f1_score(y_test,predictions_test,labels=le.classes_,average='weighted')
0.1066998393248964
```

Sklearn Accuracy score

```
accuracy_score(y_test, predictions_test)
0.11804138735062664
```

Comment: What is the activation function of the output layer? How looks your predicted data?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for this could be that you are not converting your predictions to whole number i.e. 0 or 1. Your neural network is generating an output in terms of probability of a record being of class 1. If you directly take this probabilities and evaluate it with your `y_test`, they will not match because 0.98 is not equal to 1.

Round `predictions_test` to the nearest whole number i.e. <0.5 will be 0 and >0.5 will be 1 and check accuracy.